# compile failed with gcc but success with msc++

Tags: c++, gcc

I use gcc compile, the version is (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0 in Ubuntu 18.0.4 64 bits.
The below code can be compiled success with msvc++ 2015, but failed with gcc.

```
class BaseClass
{
};

template <typename T>
class CPIPtr
{
public:
    CPIPtr()
    {
        _p = nullptr;
    }

    CPIPtr(const CPIPtr& item)
    {
        _p = nullptr;
        *this = item;
    }

    CPIPtr(BaseClass* pI)
    {
        _p = nullptr;
    }

    ~CPIPtr()
    {
    }

    operator T* () const
    {
        return _p;
    }

    T* operator=(BaseClass* pI)
    {

        return _p;
    }

private:
// public:
    T* _p;
};

#define GF_DEFINE_INTERFACE_REF_PTR(x) \
   typedef CPIPtr<x> x ## Ptr

class ITest : public BaseClass
{};

GF_DEFINE_INTERFACE_REF_PTR(ITest);

class ITest1 : public BaseClass
{};

GF_DEFINE_INTERFACE_REF_PTR(ITest1);

int main()
{
#if 0
    ITestPtr test;
    ITest1Ptr test1;

    ITest1Ptr test1 = test;
    // the above line code is equal the below two lines with msvc++
    ITest* pTest = test.operator ITest *();
    Test1.operator=(pTest);
    
#endif//0

    ITestPtr test;
    ITest1Ptr test1 = test;
    test = test1;

    return 0;
}
```

with gcc compiler, the follow error occurred.
error: conversion from ‘CPIPtr’ to non - scalar type ‘CPIPtr’ requested.

How can i solve this ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: In my project, I want to use assign operator in different Ptr object. operator T* and operator=(BaseClass* pI)  can help to complete this.

Comment: Older MSVC++ are notoriously non-conforming, try the same on a 2019 and see if it doesn't complain like gcc.

Comment: Dear Surf, I have tested the code with msvc++2019(v142) just now, it can be compiled success. Instead I think it's a fault of gcc. The gcc is not smart enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the line,

```
ITest1Ptr test1 = test;
```

This would call the copy constructor, but before that it fails in type conversion, instead use,

```
ITest1Ptr test1 = static_cast<ITest1Ptr>(test);
```

or,

```
ITest1Ptr test1 (test);
```

This following line is calling the assignment operator, which is ok,

```
test = test1;
```

Comment: I think if vc++ can't find the the right constructor function, then continue find the other  member function to complete compiling, but gcc can't find the right constructor function then report error.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
ITest1Ptr test1{test};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/192cfa8c01185bf0)

Comment: thank you very much. But Itest1Ptr(test) will call constructor function. It's not equal test1 = test.

Comment: `ITest1Ptr test1{test};` uses copy constructor, not assignment.